# Get rid of compiler warning "warning: result of call is not used"

Tags: c++, c

I am working on some legacy code which includes the below function. In summary, the function reads a line from the text file, strips leading/trailing whitespace and newline, checks for errors, and returns the number of characters in the string on success or -1 on error. Can you give me some hints to get rid of the warning? I know it's not an error but I want to improve the code. Thanks!

```
static int readline(file *mf, char *buf, int n, int strip) {
    if (!buf || n < 1 || !mf) return seterror(MDIO_BADPARAMS);

    // Read the line
    fgets(buf, n, mf->f);

    // End of file reached?
    if (feof(mf->f)) return seterror(MDIO_EOF);

    // File I/O error?
    if (ferror(mf->f)) return seterror(MDIO_IOERROR);

        // comment line?
        if (buf[0] == '#') return readline(mf,buf,n,strip);

    // Strip whitespace
    if (strip) strip_white(buf);

    return strlen(buf);
}
```

The function is able to compile (nvcc) but it has the warning:

> warning: result of call is not used

Comment: What line does it report that error on?

Comment: I think you need to show us the function call.

Comment: write `(void)` before function. E.g `(void)readline(...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fgets` is declared with the `warn_unused_result` attribute. Not checking the result is often a programming error: if `fgets` fails to read anything, it returns NULL and leaves the buffer untouched. If you don't check for this condition you might process stale or uninitialized data.

To fix this, just check the result:

```
if(!fgets(buf, n, mf->f)) return seterror(MDIO_EOF);
```